# what do they mean in C++: variable * blank and & blank

Tags: c++

8I have just learned C++ and face a sort of code like this:

```
virtual QVariant getProperty(uint ,const IContact * =0) const 
    { return QVariant(); }
virtual bool setProperty(uint ,const QVariant &,IContact * =0) 
    {return false;}
```

However, I have no idea what IContact * =0 or QVariant & mean. "IContact" and "QVariant" are classes. So I think in here they mean type of variables. But I don't understand why they only put * or & without anything after that.

Could you guys please help explaining this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's way too broad question without giving more context for these code snippets. Well it's simple to answer from a technical pov: `IContact * =0` passes a pointer to `IContact` with a default of `0`,  the function returns a `QVariant`. But it's impossible to tell the intended semantics from that snippet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, the semantics are pretty straightforward given the function names and types. It's defining an "interface" of sorts (albeit not with pure virtual functions) for subclasses to override. The `uint` is probably the property ID, the `QVariant const&` is probably the new value for setting with, and I have no idea what the optional `IContact` is for.

Comment: _@TươngNhư_ If you can't sort out what that technically means, you didn't _learn c++_ actually!

Comment: Thank guys! Actually I have just studied C++ a couple of days to understand this kind of codes my Prof gave me. In some books I read, the Icontact * and Qvariant & look like defining a pointer or reference variable. But the syntax usually have the variable names after * or &. In this case, it is empty and that confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function's parameter is unused, you don't have to give it a name. In this case, these functions are `virtual`, meaning they're expected to be overridden by a derived class, which may use these parameters in the overridden function definitions.

`const IContact* = 0` means an unused parameter of type "pointer to const `IContact`" whose value is not required to be specified by the caller, and null is used if the caller omits its value.

`const QVariant&` is an unused parameter of type "reference to const `QVariant`". The caller must still specify its value, however.

Comment: Nice try, see my comment on the OP.

Comment: Also, although I haven't done any Googling, `QVariant` is probably a variant type from Qt so this is probably from a KDE program or library. It's still just a guess, of course, but in a minute I'll Google it and I'll get a clearer picture. :-)

Comment: I've got serious doubts, if such poor question will actually provide value for future research :-P ...

Comment: Yeah, Googling for `"qvariant getproperty" icontact` didn't return any useful results. :-(

Comment: Arguable, if it's about Google fu, reading some books about the basic c++ idioms, or dig into how Qt framework handles properties ;-).

Comment: Many thanks Chris, As I have just study C++ and thought it should have a variable name after * or &. In this case, its empty. That's why I was confused